# X axis date/time format issues with xts object in r

Tags: r

I have been using R for several years, but could really use some help with this. Time series data is not my norm. For some background, this data comes from I-buttons, which record temperature that were planted in different sized patches in a landscape. My data looks like this in general:

```
    Ibutton_new.csv:

    Date      Edge1  Edge2 Edge3...
    2012-7-16 25     24    24.5
    2012-7-16 24     23    23
    2012-7-16 23.5   22.5  22.5
    2012-7-16 27.5   24.5  24.5
    2012-7-16 27     27.5  26.5
    2012-7-16 27     26.5  27
    2012-7-17 26     25    25
    2012-7-17 25     25    25
    2012-7-17 24     23    23
    2012-7-17 24     23    23
    2012-7-17 28     29    27.5
    2012-7-17 28     28    28
    etc for a year
```

Step 1: I convert my data into an xts object:

```
    library(zoo)
    library(xts)
    x<-read.csv("Ibutton_new.csv")
    x$Date <- mdy(x$Date)
    x.xts <- xts(x[,-1], order.by=x[,1])
    class(x.xts)
    [1] "xts" "zoo"
    str(x.xts)
    An ‘xts’ object on 2012-07-16/2013-06-22 containing:
    Data: num [1:2048, 1:114] 25 24 23.5 27.5 27 27 26 25 24 28 ...
    - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
    ..$ : NULL
    ..$ : chr [1:114] "edge_1" "edge_2" "edge_3" "edge_4" ...
    Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
    xts Attributes:  
    NULL
```

Step 2:Make a graph

```
    windows()
    plot(x.xts,col=color1,main="Soil Temperature (C) Across Whole 
    Site",lwd=2,ylim=c(-10,50),cex.axis=1.5)
```

[image]

Okay, in general I am pretty happy with this, except for the x axis which is just ugly. I don't know why it is putting time stamps with the date values? I would like it just to have tick marks and labels by month. So I tried this:

```
    plot(x.xts,col=color1,main="Soil Temperature (C) Across Whole 
    Site",lwd=2,ylim=c(-10,50),cex.axis=1.5,major.ticks="months",grid.ticks.on="months")
```

So grid lines and tick marks looked fine, but the labels were still the same. Then I tried this:

```
    plot(x.xts,xaxt="n",col=color1,main="Soil Temperature (C) Across Whole 
    Site",lwd=2,ylim=c(-10,50),cex.axis=1.5)
    ticks <- axTicksByTime(x.xts,"months",format.labels="%b-%Y")
    axis(1,at = .index(x.xts)[ticks], labels = names(ticks),mgp=c(0,0.5,0))
```

And hilariously got this:
[image]

So I am so close, but not quite there. Any suggestions? Normally I would just import this into powerpoint and edit it. I have an add on that can export high quality pictures, but my computer is in a repair shop right now. Also, I hate feeling like R got the best of me. I am sure there is an easy solution or something silly I did but am not seeing, possibly a formatting issue in step one? It took me forever to be able to even make a proper xts object. Again, I don't normally work with this type of data or packages. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `axis()` just adds a formatted axis over the existing plot, similar to `lines()`, for example.

The solution is to include the formatting you want in the original call to `plot()` like so:

```
plot(x.xts,xaxt="n",col=color1,main="Soil Temperature (C) Across Whole 
    Site",lwd=2,ylim=c(-10,50),cex.axis=1.5, format.labels="%b-%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks phalteman! That totally worked. I knew it would be something easy I was missing. I read so many other posts (for like 2 hours) trying to figure this out. Now I can make pretty graphs to show to my boss today. :)